# how do I check whether a plot was written to file in R

Tags: r, plot

If I execute the following R code, a file will be created

```
png('tempfile.png', width = 500, height = 500)
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

If I don't plot anything. No file is created.

```
png('tempfile.png', width = 500, height = 500)
#plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

What is the best way to check whether the file was created at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file.exists`

```
file.exists("tempfile.png")
```

If you are modifying files you can also check when a file was last modified with `file.info` in the `mtime` column.  There is also creation time `ctime` and last access time `atime` along with a few other metrics that may or may not be of interest to you.

Comment: It looks like this is the only possibility. Thank you! I was hoping that there is a direct way to get feedback whether a plot has been written to file or not. I will accept this answer.